# Database Testing Automation using Java - Trigger ETL JoB

Tags: java, database, testing, automation, etl

I have written tests in Java to validate data from database based on some event took place in an application, As soon as that event happens it updates and adds few records in database.

***Ex:***

**Table Name**: RecordsStatus

**Column Name**: Status -> Flag 0 or 1

If this is 1 we have to run an ETL Job and have to verify some other tables that are updated based on ETL job, so there are 3 stages here that are to be tested

Some Action happens in an Application (**No need to Test this**)

1. Flag is updated in database table
2. Run ETL Job
3. Verify data that is updated

The entire process has to be in one single test as the unique id has to be used in all the 3 stages for validating the data.

I am thinking to write a listener in Java that checks for Flag from "RecordStatus" table based on which the ETL job has to run

Is this a good approach?, please suggest if there are any better approaches

Are there any open source tools to do similar testing